# Java swing/awt tabbed pane event

Tags: java, events, swing

I'm new to java so bear with me:

I want the size of the window/pane/panel to chance once the tab is clicked/changed.

How would I do/impletement this?

I've done it successfully on a button click/event, but how do I do a tab click/event?

Here is my code: (I'm sorry for any bad/bloated/unnessicary code in advance)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener; 

//Class shows how to setup up a tabbed window
public class GUI implements ActionListener
{
static JFrame aWindow = new JFrame("Project");
JTabbedPane myTabs = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel loginMainPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel displayMainPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel editMainPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
JTextField loginField = new JTextField();
JLabel loginLabel2 = new JLabel("Password:");
JPasswordField loginPass = new JPasswordField();
JButton displayButton = new JButton("Press This Button");
JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
JLabel editLabel = new JLabel("Write a story:");
JTextArea editArea = new JTextArea();
public GUI()
{
Toolkit theKit = aWindow.getToolkit();
Dimension wndSize=theKit.getScreenSize();
aWindow.setBounds(wndSize.width/3, wndSize.height/3, 200, 200); //set position, then dimensions
aWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(1,1);
Container content = aWindow.getContentPane();
content.setLayout(grid);
createLoginPanel();
createDisplayPanel();
createEditPanel();
myTabs.addTab("Login", loginMainPanel);
myTabs.addTab("Display", displayMainPanel);
myTabs.addTab("Edit", editMainPanel);
myTabs.setSelectedIndex(0);
//myTabs.setEnabledAt(1,false);
myTabs.setEnabledAt(2, false);
content.add(myTabs);
aWindow.setVisible(true);
}

public void createLoginPanel()
{
loginMainPanel.setLayout(null);
loginLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 150, 20);
loginMainPanel.add(loginLabel);
loginField.setBounds(10, 35, 150, 20);
loginMainPanel.add(loginField);
loginLabel2.setBounds(10, 60, 150, 20);
loginMainPanel.add(loginLabel2);

loginPass.setBounds(10, 80, 150, 20);

loginMainPanel.add(loginPass);
loginButton.addActionListener(this);
loginButton.setBounds(50, 110, 80, 20);
loginMainPanel.add(loginButton);
}

public void createDisplayPanel()
{
//Toolkit theKit = aWindow.getToolkit();
//Dimension wndSize = theKit.getScreenSize();
//aWindow.setBounds(20, 20, 20, 20); //set position, then dimensions

displayMainPanel.setLayout(null);
displayButton.addActionListener(this);
displayButton.setBounds(10, 80, 150, 20);
displayMainPanel.add(displayButton);
}

public void createEditPanel()
{
editMainPanel.setLayout(null);
editLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 150, 20);
editMainPanel.add(editLabel);
editArea.setBounds(10, 65, 150, 50);
editMainPanel.add(editArea); 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

{

if (e.getSource() == loginButton)
{
//System.out.println("Working...");
Toolkit theKit = aWindow.getToolkit();
Dimension wndSize = theKit.getScreenSize();
aWindow.setBounds(wndSize.width / 4, wndSize.height / 4, 300, 300);
}

//Would the event go here?

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
GUI tw1 = new GUI();
} 

}
```

Thanks very much :)

James,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but how do I do a tab click/event?

Use a ChangeListener.

Comment: See "How to Write a Change Listener" (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html)